# How to import/export filters from logcat window?

Tags: android-studio

I'm use Android Studio. I added several filters at `Logcat` window.

I migrate from 3.1 to 3.2. When I run new version of Android Studio, most of settings imported from old directory (.AndroidStudioPreview3.1). But filters in `Logcat` window are empty. I need add them manually.

How I can import/export this filters? Or maybe needed copy some directory/files?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should keep `.idea` directory.
Filters are stored at `/.idea/workspace.xml` (component with name *AndroidConfiguredLogFilters*).